# Ошибки из другого проекта

Tags: winforms

Объясните. пожалуйста, почему в запускаю код в одном проекте(CW), а списке ошибок есть другой (HW)

form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CW_Form
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Text = "Hello World!";
            this.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
            this.Width = 250;
            this.Height = 250;
            this.Size = new Size(1100, 850);
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine;
            this.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("D:\\e1.jpg");
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

            

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 newForm = new Form2(this);
            newForm.Show();
        }

    }
}
```

form2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CW_Form
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Form2(Form1 f)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            f.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }


    }
}
```

form1_desinger

```
namespace CW_Form
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">истинно, если управляемый ресурс должен быть удален; иначе ложно.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Код, автоматически созданный конструктором форм Windows

        /// <summary>
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1_Click = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1_Click
            // 
            this.button1_Click.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(421, 142);
            this.button1_Click.Name = "button1_Click";
            this.button1_Click.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1_Click.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1_Click.Text = "button1";
            this.button1_Click.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1_Click);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Компилируется всё решение (solution) целиком. Проект входит в это решение, значит компилируется.

Comment: Как это исправить?